# limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Help me please to find:
$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )}$

Thanks.

Comment: It helps to think about what happens when n = 1000, n = 100000, n = 1000000000 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )}$
$=\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln3+\log n-\log{10} }$

This is of the form $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$

So, we can apply [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html),

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )}
=\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln3+\log n-\log{10} }
=\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac1{\frac 1n}=\lim_{n \to \infty } n=\infty$$

---

Alternatively without using L'Hospital's Rule,

let $\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )=m,n=\frac {10}3 e^m$ and $m\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$

So, $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\ln\left ( \frac{3n}{10} \right )}
=\frac{10}3\lim_{m \to \infty }\frac{e^m}m 
=\frac{10}3\lim_{m \to \infty }\frac{1+\frac m{1!}+\frac {m^2}{2!}+\cdots }m$$
$$=\frac{10}3\cdot\lim_{m \to \infty }\{ \frac 1m +m+\frac m{2!}+\cdots\}=\infty
$$

Comment: You forgot a lim.

Comment: @N.U., thanks . Rectified.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thank you very much

Comment: @Tina, welcome. Hope I could clear the idea.